# How to populate data to a Json Template

Tags: java, json, templates, jsonpath

I have a Json Format as a Template (Temp.json). Below is the format of my Template

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "ProductTitleName": "",
      "ImageUrl":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have to Populate Data to this format, basically **products** array will have many object Nodes. I have used JsonPath expressions to extract relevant attribute value from Raw Json.My Problem is how can I use this Template and Populate data to this structure.

`Reason to use Template Json` -

1. I used a Template json to avoid pojo classes
2. Though JsonPath expressions helps to extract necessary attributes and set them to target attribute final Json out put result I build previously is on-the-fly (Runtime).
3. If suppose I'm going to add another attribute along with those attributes later, it would be easier and to good avoid code changes.

so to avoid those mentioned reasons, I planned to have a Template json and adhere to that structure, is this a good approach, if so help me out to populate data to the template, if not help me out with a better approach.

Comment: How would the template help you to populate the products array if you don't know before how long it would be? Also, there's more to building JSON than just concatenating text: there are escaping rules you need to take into account etc. If you really don't want to use pojos for this (why is that exactly) I would recommend using a streaming approach instead (e.g. Jackson streaming API)

Comment: @marthursson I am trying to define a template because my requirements might change later on (i.e. i might have to another attribute to the product object so in that case i have to come and edit my pojo class right) its like editing my code again which is bad according to SOLID principle, so i thought of having a template where i can go and add that attribute so easily i dont have to change the code.

Comment: @marthursson In terms of how long my product array is, anyhow through my Template i define the attributes of a general project object and each project object in the product array gonna have ideal same attributes just the value is gonna change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need only **to avoid pojo** classes you can **use a generic `Map`** to do the same. In this case you don't need to parse the basic template.

```
Map<String, Object> products = new HashMap<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> listProducts = new ArrayList<>();

for () { // Loop over products
    Map<String, Object> product = new HashMap<>();
    product.put("ProductTitleName", "YourTitle");
    product.put("ImageUrl", "YourImageUrl");
    listProducts.add(product);
}

products.put("products", listProducts);
// Now you can use products Map instead of an equivalent pojo class
```

---

If you need to use a template try to use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/). It is a template engine that works well to build text file (in this case a json file), but  from a template. It is not limited to files, it works also with strings or streams if necessary.

Comment: Thankyou for quick response, but imagine if i'm going to add more attributes later, at that time i have to come and edit this code right, i need have a another put statement that's a bad thing to do right according to SOLIDS principle, if i have a template i can simply go and add another attribute no code change, hope i make sense to you

Comment: How do you think to add new attributes if you don't know that they exists and how you can extract them from another java object?

Comment: The template.json here helps to give the structure of each product object, I define Rules (JsonPath Expressions - to extract and map it to exact attribute in the template json attribute) like below             

     ` "rules": [
        {
          "source": "$.payload.recommendations[*].products[*].productTitle",
          "target": "$.products[*].productTitle"
        },
        {
          "source": "$.payload.recommendations[*].products[*].image.url",
          "target": "$.products[*].imageUrl"
        }
      ]`

Comment: so if i add a new attribute to my template.json i come and have a new rule in this config file for that particular attribute to map the relevant raw json attribute

Comment: @kesh read the updated answer. Basically instead of using JsonPath use Velocity, it is a better product to do that.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time I will try velocity and get back to you soon with this post.

Comment: It just took time for me to study the engine and implement and atlast it just worked, thanks for that redirection

Comment: @kesh you are wellcome. Velocity is one of the most known template engines. You can apply it in different situations. This one for me was a good case of application.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO is there any way wherein I can have java code, which is very generic and take any kind of json template and field data in csv and generate json.  please note that json is having multiple levels of  inner data (like array of json)

Comment: @begin a Map can be used to represent any kind of son. All properties are the first level are keys of that map. The values can be: strings, numbers (long, int, double, ...), booleans to represent the primitive types of json. But you can also use Map for objects and lists for arrays. And to the same for each level deep to your leaves.